# Get Facebook photo id by it's external source url

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm uploading photos to Facebook page album by script. Each photo is specified with external, non-facebook url, so actually these urls are uploaded, representing photos.

Some time after upload I may need to check if given photo was uploaded (it's possible, that it was not marked as uploaded by script).

Is it possible in Facebook API to obtain uploaded photo id, using it's external source url, by which it was uploaded?

Comment: No that is not possible.

Comment: If you are pretty sure, maybe you can post this as an aswer? Then I'll mark it as excepted. To @WizKid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted @WizKid in a comment to issue, getting photo ID by it's original external source url is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

After you upload the picture you get an id as a response of your post request.

```
curl -i -X POST \
 -d "url=https://www.facebook.com/images/fb_icon_325x325.png" \
 -d "caption=test photo upload" \
 -d "access_token=<user_photos_user_access_token>" \
 "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.11/me/photos"
```

I'm pretty sure you can query that id using get request to https://graph.facebook.com/v2.11/{id-of-photo}

You can also use the Graph Api Explorer to learn of the fields available for that object.

[Graph Api Explorer](https://developers.intern.facebook.com/tools/explorer/)

Comment: Question is not about the Facebook object id, but about the original URL the image was uploaded _from_ ...

Comment: Yep @JorgeO, I know about getting photo id in response. The question was about the situation, when I can not use this id to check if photo exists (it might happen for certain reasons), and can only use photo external url